# Should the tutorial Notepadv3 close its database?

Tags: android, notepad

Android’s [Notepad tutorial Notepadv3](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) opens its database but never explicitly closes it. To make it *correct*, should Notepadv3 close its database, presumably with `mDbHelper.close();` and, if so, where should that line of code appear?

**Updated with a related question**: The **close** method of **NotesDbAdapter** in the tutorial is implemented via `mDbHelper.close()`. Would it be equally effective to implement the **close** method via `mDb.close()`? In other words, is the **close** method of **SQLiteDatabase** equivalent to the **close** method of **SQLiteOpenHelper** and, if not, why is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should close the adapter and cursors once you don't need them anymore (for instance, when you finish your activity). That should be executed on the `onDestroy` method.

Comment: Note that the reason for `onDestroy()` in this case is because the database is opened in `onCreate()`. Ideally, you should stick with the lifecycle pairs.

Comment: That answer makes sense. I wonder why it wasn’t included in the tutorial example code. Since a lot of new developers to Android will use that tutorial as their starting point, they will initially miss the need to properly close the database.

Comment: @Mike Green, thanks for your question. Was wondering also why I get errors in LogCat with Notepad3 code.

Comment: @LA_, yes the lack of the use of any close method to close the database in Notepadv3 causes error messages in LogCat. That is a bit disconcerting for a newcomer, who might be using the tutorial to learn to develop with Android. I don’t think the tutorial example needs to be a perfect app in every sense but it should be error free in basic areas, such as closing its database on exit.